# How to add an addListener function for an object javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have add an listen event for a marker such as

```
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });
});

// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
});

markerCluster.addListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click action');
});
```

When I click into a marker on google map. My click function doesn't work. How to implement this task?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @Scimonster: When I click into a marker on google map. My click funtion doesn't work

Comment: Right now you have no code in the click function.

Comment: Don't you need to add a specific 'Google' click event handler to make this work?

Comment: @Scimonster: I eddited my post. Don't thing happen when I click on a marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need a custom Google click handler like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
  // your code here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the listener to the marker object.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

```
marker.addListener('click', function(){
    // do something here.
})
```

since you are returning it in your function as an array it would be ...

```
for(id in markers) { 
    markers[id].addListener('click',function(){
        //your code});     
}
```

That should work.

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michael_coder/30oy992j/)

Comment: I tried!. Error : `Uncaught TypeError: markers.addListener is not a function
`

Comment: I'll make a jsfiddle

Comment: If you are using google maps v3 then it should be working. You can check out the JSFiddle I added to my answer.

Comment: This is solution. Just only display infor box when I click on nunber marker. I also want to display infor box when clicking on alphabet marker

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5oew3oc5/)

Comment: Okay I see what's going on. You are appending all of the markers to an array so you have to loop through each marker in order to add a listener to each. like this           for(id in markers) { markers[id].addListener('click',function(){ //your code});     That should work.

Comment: Please upvote and check as the correct answer if this solved your problem.